# Need a formula for cumulative moving averages in Open Office

Tags: database, openoffice.org, average, calculator, moving-average

I have data in column A, and would like to put the averages in column B like this:

```
    a     b
1   10    10 
2   7     8.5
3   8     8.333
4   19    11
5   13    11.5
```

where b1 =average(a1), b2 =average(a1:a2), b3 =average(a1:a3)....

Using average() is alright for small amounts of data, but I have over 1500 data entries. I would like to find a more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your initial range reference absolute, while the other is relative, i.e.:

```
b4 = average($a$1:a4)
```

You can paste that 1500 times an it will always increment the end of the range while keeping the beginning pinned to `A1` due to the dollar signs in that reference.